# How blockchain nodes maintain one global version of transactions

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, ethereum, hyperledger

I understand Consensus rules and P2P networking. But since a node is connected only to some limited number of other peers, So a subset of nodes will only know a limited reality of blocks know among these peers at least at a given point of time. How all the nodes sync up and have all the global blocks relayed among themselves.

For example sake, let's assume there are only 6 nodes globally and they happen to get following pairing to peers.

```
1<-->2      
2<-->3  
3<-->1

4<-->5  
5<--6>  
6<-->4
```

It leads to kind of two isolated groups of 3 each. Let's assume now Adam's wallet is connected to node 4 and does a transaction. How will this be relayed to nodes 1, 2 and 3?
Of course, it would be desirable to have them relayed in say a few minutes if not in seconds.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question. You may be able to get help on [bitcoin.se].

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: The longest chain is always the accepted chain.

Long answer: [Look here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/72662/what-would-happen-if-two-miners-were-mining-two-blocks-with-two-different-set-of/72670#72670).

Comment: Thanks. I understand the forks. However, my question is not about simultaneous blocks getting mined. It's about inconsistent state of different nodes globally. Eg. Consider, that Adam in my example can do a double spend by a. Do a transaction on 1 set of nodes which know about Adam's transaction. b. Do another spend by managing to connect to different set of nodes where the changes of original transactions have not yet propagated.

Comment: Why does that matter if one chain will eventually survive, which is the longest chain? Who cares if the final chain is consistent? Why do you think you need 6 confirmation for transactions? Please think further about your question and don't rush to comment here. Also read about the gossip protocol to understand how broadcasting happens.